# How to make one checbox checked at a time and to toggle the checked to unchecked when other checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How to make the checkbox click at a time when one is clicked and other should be unchecked. 
when checkbox one is clicked it should be marked to checked and when checkbox two is clicked it should be marked checked and rest all should be marked unchecked.

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="feedback-quest3">
    <label class="checkbox ques3" for="ques3-cbox1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="ques3-cbox1" data-toggle="checkbox">
        1-2 
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox ques3" for="ques3-cbox2">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="ques3-cbox2" data-toggle="checkbox">
        2-3 
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox ques3" for="ques3-cbox3">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="ques3-cbox3" data-toggle="checkbox">
        3-4 
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use radio buttons? That's exactly what they are designed for.

Comment: Sounds like you want a radio button, not a checkbox

Comment: Yeah i know that, but in my project they need in that way only means a user should be able to click only one checkbox functionality similar to radio button.

Comment: You need to understand UX, When I as a user see checkboxes it means I can select one or more of them

Comment: You only think you want a set of mutually exclusive checkboxes.  What you really want are radio buttons (you can always change their look and feel).

Answer (score 1):

See the <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Q5n/1/)**</kbd>

#### Javascript

```
function attach(element,listener,ev,tf){    
  if(element.attachEvent)    
      element.attachEvent("on"+listener,ev);    
  else    
    element.addEventListener(listener,ev,tf);
}

var parent = document.getElementById('parentElement');
var checkboxes = parent.getElementsByTagName('input');

if(checkboxes.length>0){        
    for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){            
       attach(checkboxes[i],'click',function(event){        
          var evt = event || window.event;
          var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;       
          for(var y=0;y<checkboxes.length;y++){             
            checkboxes[y].checked = false;                   
          }    
          target.checked = true;        
       }, false);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".feedback-quest3 :checkbox").on("change", function(){
  $(".feedback-quest3 :checkbox").not($(this)).prop("checked",false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, try this:

```
$(".feedback-quest3 :checkbox").each(function(){
  $(".feedback-quest3 :checkbox").on("change",function(){
     $(".feedback-quest3 :checkbox").prop("checked",false);
     $(this).prop("checked",true);
  });
});
```